# Spark - jdbc write fails in Yarn cluster mode but works in spark-shell

Tags: sql-server, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, jdbc

I am using Spark 1.6.2, Hadoop 2.6, Scala 2.10.5 and Java 1.7

I am using JDBC to read data from MSSQL and this works without any problem:

```
val hqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.1.1:1111;database=CIQOwnershipProcessing;user=OwnershipUser;password=Ownership123"

val driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

val df1 = hqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
   Map("url" -> url, "driver" -> driver,
  "dbtable" -> "(select * from OwnershipStandardization_PositionSequence_tbl) as ps")).load()
```

And, while writing back dataframe to MSSQL, I am using the JDBC write as shown below. This works fine in Spark-shell but fails when I do spark-submit in Yarn-Cluster mode. What am I missing ?

```
val prop = new java.util.Properties
df1.write.mode("Overwrite").jdbc(url, "CIQOwnershipProcessing.dbo.df_sparkop",prop)
```

This is how my spark-submit command looks like. As you can see, I am passing the SQLJDBC jar path too. And, I have also specified the jdbc jar path in "spark.executor.extraClassPath" property in spark-defaults.conf on all nodes of the cluster. Since the JDBC read is working, I doubt if it has anything to do with the classpaths.

```
spark-submit --class com.spgmi.csd.OshpStdCarryOver --master  yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 3g --executor-memory 8g --jars $SPARK_HOME/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,$SPARK_HOME/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,$SPARK_HOME/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/share/java/sqljdbc_4.1/enu/sqljdbc41.jar --files $SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/lib/spark-poc2-17.1.0.jar
```

The error thrown in the Yarn-Cluster mode is:

> 17/01/05 10:21:31 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw
>   exception: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper
>   java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:368)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:53)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:52)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:278)
>           at com.spgmi.csd.OshpStdCarryOver$.main(SparkOshpStdCarryOver.scala:175)
>           at com.spgmi.csd.OshpStdCarryOver.main(SparkOshpStdCarryOver.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:558)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I resolved it by setting connection property in prop.

```
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

now pass this prop in

```
df1.write.mode("Overwrite").jdbc(url, "CIQOwnershipProcessing.dbo.df_sparkop",prop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem feels very similar to [SPARK-14204](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14204) and [SPARK-14162](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14162) -- although that bug was supposed to be fixed in Spark 1.6.2 (?!)

With a Type 4 JDBC driver you should not have to *explicitly* mention the "driver" property; the JAR should automatically register the URL prefix that it supports (here `jdbc:sqlserver:`).
But because of the bug, the Spark JDBC module may not use that "registration" to find the driver that *implicitly* matches the URL.

In other words: for reading, you force the "driver" property and the connection works; for writing, you don't force it, and it does not work. Aha!

Comment: Yes, that is what I'd like to know. How do you force the "Driver" property in JDBC write ? Thanks!

Comment: The Spark documentation does not state that "driver" is specific to reading, so what about `df1.write.mode("Overwrite").format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> url, "driver" -> driver, "dbtable" -> "xxxxx")).save()`? Cf. the unit tests in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JDBCWriteSuite.scala for example.

Comment: No that is not working, I see this error:

`17/01/10 06:12:13 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select.`

Comment: @Prash, that's a *different* issue -- my guess is that Spark does not support `Overwrite` mode for a JDBC save; try with `Append` mode instead.

Comment: Hi Samson, still no luck. Getting the exact same error. This is how my jdbc write statement looks like:

`df1_rnum.write.mode("Append").format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> url, "driver" -> driver, "dbtable" -> "CIQOwnershipProcessing.dbo.df_rnum_sparkop")).save()`